# How do I enable wake on LAN in the Alienware BIOS

Tags: bios, wake-on-lan

I have an Alienware Area 51 R2, with BIOS version A14. How do I enable wake on LAN (WOL) in the BIOS? I can't find the setting anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

According to [a post from randye007 on a Dell forum](https://www.dell.com/community/Alienware-Desktops/Enabling-Wake-on-LAN-WOL-for-Aurora-R6/td-p/6043501) and [a Dell knowledge base article](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln307243/newer-dell-system-models-will-not-wake-on-lan-with-deep-sleep-control-set-to-s5-in-the-windows?lang=en), you need to enter power options and disable "Deep Sleep". Once that's disabled, the option to enable Wake on LAN will appear.

(**Note:** I ask and answer this question here because it was very difficult to find these pages.)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I have determined that the following is no longer required, not sure why (perhaps PEBCAK or inexperience with WOL?). Original answer below for posterity & educational purposes.**

In addition to Kyle's answer I also needed to in the BIOS go to:

```
Advanced > Integrated Devices > Pxe Option > UEFI PXE Driver 
Change Disabled to Enabled
```

The defaults of `Enabled` for Ipv4 and Ipv6, just worked for me.

Comment: That's a bit odd that PXE boot would need to be enabled for WOL, as it should work simply by enabling WOL in the BIOS or UEFI firmware settings _and_ within the LAN adapter's properties in the OS. PXE boot is a potential security risk on a machine that isn't intended to PXE boot, as it allows forcing the PC to boot a PXE OS image _(WinPE, WinRE, BSD/Linux distros, etc.)_, bypassing user authentication entirely for the WOL PC since PXE boot occurs at the BIOS/UEFI Firmware level prior to either handing off to the installed OS' bootloader.